# Retrieving parent row only if all children are deleted in mysql query

Tags: mysql, rdbms

Let's say i have a draft table: Each Parent having a unique id and it's parent column set to null.

draft:

```
id |  parent_id | is_deleted
--- ------------ ------------
 1 |  null      | 0
 2 |    1       | 0
 3 |    1       | 1
 4 |   null     | 0
 5 |    4       | 1
 6 |    4       | 1
 7 |    4       | 0
 8 |   null     | 0
 9 |    8       | 1
```

Now i want get a list of parents that have all their deleted only.

```
select id 
from draft
where id in (
  select parent_id
  from draft
  where id in (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9)
  group by parent_id
  having sum(case when is_deleted 0 then 1 else 0) <= 0
)
where is_deleted = 0;
```

The problem here is it always returning the parent's 1, 4, and 8. But it should only be returning 8.

**UPDATE**: I want the parent row and not the parent id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select * from draft
where id in
(
    select parent_id from draft a where is_deleted = 1
    and not exists
    (select 1 from draft b where a.parent_id = b.parent_id and is_deleted = 0)
)
```

You can also use `JOIN` instead of `IN`

```
select draft.* from draft 
join(
    select parent_id from draft a where is_deleted = 1
    and not exists
    (select 1 from draft b where a.parent_id = b.parent_id and is_deleted = 0)
) p on parent.id = p.parent_id
```

Comment: is_deleted = 1 and is_deleted=0 is that from the parent draft?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
select a.*
  from draft a
  join
    (select distinct parent_id
    from draft d
    where (select count(*) from draft e 
           where e.is_deleted = 0 and e.parent_id = d.parent_id) = 0) b
  on a.id=b.parent_id
```

I have assumed you want the parent_id returned rather than the id, since your description implies the former, while your actual sql implies the latter.

Comment: i want the row of the parent because i want do some processing on the parent row and not the child row. The reason being is that i will be taking a list of id's from UI.

Comment: Edited to match requirement (I hope). Even if it does the job I am sure there is shorter/better performing sql to achieve this, but I'll leave that to you to find!